# How do i call a KeyEvent method from one class to another?

Tags: java, class, methods

After doing a few small things i have decided to try my hand at a text based rpg. I am only using the console as i again am learning still. I am however at this point running into an issue i cant seem to get passed nor find any help on. I have my Game class which holds my main method as well as a few other classes one of which is my Player class. Within my Player class i have this:

```
public void playerControls(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) 
    {
        System.out.println("Up");
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) 
    {
        System.out.println("Left");
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) 
    {
        System.out.println("Down");
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) 
    {
        System.out.println("Right");
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_I) 
    {
        System.out.println("Inventory");
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_O)
    {
        System.out.println("Options");
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_M)
    {
        System.out.println("Map");
    }   
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_C)
    {   
        System.out.println("Character");

    }
}
```

Then inside of my Game class i have within my main method:

```
//START OF GAME     
    do
    {

    player.playerControls(e);   

    validInput = true;


    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!enter the intro story here!!!!!!!!!");



    } while (gameRun);



}
```

The problem i am having is that i get an error saying e cannot be resolved to a variable when i run it as null i also throw errors. My question is how do I (like this/also "properly") call the playerControls from my players class into my Game class so that i can run the game and allow user input. Thank you for any answers. Have a great day :)

Comment: The `KeyEvent` is generated by a `KeyListener`.You'd have to register a listener to the console(which I am not sure how to do) to actually get a `KeyEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So essentially the console is what would be looking for any user input and I would have to set the console to do so, where as the KeyEvent is what happens if the console senses any input?

Comment: You're confused: KeyEvent and console don't mix and shouldn't mix as the former is part of an event-driven user interface GUI library and the latter is part of a linear programming user interface. The answer is don't use KeyEvents if you're doing simple console programming. Use a BufferedReader or a Scanner as most any tutorial will show you.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Hovercraft I was def confused makes sence why I could find any answers to that in particular. Meik thank you for the example didn't realize I could do that with the console input and switch statements I have done so I'll give that a try. Got a bit ahead of myself I think lol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your method require a `KeyEvent` you can just read the console input.

```
do {
    String input = System.console().readLine();
    //Change playerControls(KeyEvent e) to playerControls(String e)
    player.playerControls(input);   
    validInput = true;
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!enter the intro story here!!!!!!!!!");
} while (gameRun);
```

Yes there is a way to do this with a single `Char` instead of a `String`, but it is not easy enough in my opinion for a starter.

Now you also would have to change your `playerControls`-method further:

```
public void playerControls(String e){        
    switch(e){
        case "Up": system.out.println("Up");
               break;
        //Do so with all controls
    }
```

Instead of the `break` which is to stop executing every following case(which will happen if you forget the `break`) you could use `return;`.